# iOS 11: Scroll to top when "adjustedContentInset" changes with larger title bars?

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit, ios11

I noticed that this code doesn't quite work as expected on iOS 11, because the "**adjustedContentInset**" property value changes as the "**navigationBar**" shrinks during a scroll:

```
CGFloat contentInsetTop=[scrollView contentInset].top;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
{
    contentInsetTop=[scrollView adjustedContentInset].top;

}
////

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -contentInsetTop) animated:YES];
```

... For example, this might start out as `140`, then reduce to `88` beyond a minimal scroll offset. This means if you call this, it doesn't actually scroll all the way to the top.

Aside from preserving the original offset in memory from when the `UIScrollView` loads, is there a way to recover this value later to ensure that it does indeed scroll to top consistently, no matter the "**adjustedContentInset**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is indeed no way to do this with iOS 11, I have heard. The only way to do so is to capture the initial value and store it for the life of the navigation/view controller.

I will update my answer accordingly if I hear otherwise, but it will be broken in the base iOS 11 release forever unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a Large Title in iOS 11, and the following code worked for me.

The following code first scrolls the offset a reasonable size above where you want to be. The value -204.666666666667 was the tallest value from setting the Accessibility > Larger Text > Larger Accessibility Sizes to the highest. I'm sure this doesn't cover other possibilities, but it is working for me so far. -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude is otherwise too problematic.

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -204.666666666667), animated: false)
```

This will now give you back the right adjusted content size. To avoid being scrolled too far higher, i.e. leaving white space, just use the value as follows.

```
var contentOffset = CGPoint.zero // Just setting a variable we can change as needed below, as per iOS version.

if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -tableView.adjustedContentInset.top)
} else {
    contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top)
}

tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

In summary, set the offset higher first (-204.666666666667 in my case, or just -300 or whatever), then that readjusts the adjustedContentInset.top to include the Large Title, scroll bar, etc., then you can now set the content offset as needed.